# Slick carousel in Center Mode causes SlidesToscroll does not work as it should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

In slick carousel(Slick.js), I would like to use centerPadding so I have to set centerMode to true. After I turn CenterMode on, I swipe the slides but it moves just only one slide per swipe no matter how much I drag/swipe the carousel from side to side. If I change centerMode to false, the carousel works properly but centerPadding does not work.

In summary
centerMode: true //Turn this false then the slideToScoll works but centerPadding doesn't work 
centerPadding: "30px" //Work only if centerMode is true 
slideToScroll: 3 //This doesn't works, only 1 slide scroll per swipe

I want those options of slicks carousel works together, centerMode with CenterPadding and number of slideToScroll works as indicated.

Is that possible?

Comment: if you were able to solve your problem, it will help if you can share the answer with everyone, or check the answer that helped solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your issue correctly, this can be resolved by using:

`swipeToSlide: true`

in your settings.

That will cause swipe/drag to stop on the slide you actually swiped to, rather than the next slide.

But there is no way to make certerMode and slideToScroll, both to work at the same time.